# Julia adding package from github

Tags: julia

I want to install the following package from github. I tried using the following command in my environment to install

```
(nlpEnvJl) pkg> add "https://github.com/yeesian/LeafletJS.jl/tree/master/src"
```

But I get the following error,

ERROR: could not find project file in package at `https://github.com/yeesian/LeafletJS.jl` maybe `subdir` needs to be specified

Any ideas on how I can get installed? Do I have to clone it first to my local repo? If so how do I install from local path?

Cheers
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: `add https://github.com/yeesian/LeafletJS.jl` , although this seems like a very old package, specifically lacking the `Project.toml` file (which is the error you are receiving), you might need to use an old version of julia.

Comment: Yep didn't work but thanks for the comment

Comment: I believe the current syntax for add would be `using Pkg; Pkg.add(url="https://github.com/yeesain/LeafletJS.jl")`, adding `rev="master"` and/or `subdir="tree/master/src"` if necessary.

Answer (score 19):

You do not need to install locally, but you have to put the URL official to clone it.

```
add https://github.com/yeesian/LeafletJS.jl.git
```

Sometimes, if the package is already registered and you only want the main version in github you can directly do

```
add PackageName#main
```

Comment: If you want a subfolder of the git repo (e.g., you want to include CairoMakie from https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl/tree/master/CairoMakie), add the subfolder after a colon. `add https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl#master:CairoMakie`

Answer (score 8):

You have to clone it locally and then use `Pkg.generate` in order to import it as a package. It needs a `Project.toml` file to be added.

Thus, you have to:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:yeesian/LeafletJS.jl.git                                                                                                                                                                                       
Cloning into 'LeafletJS.jl'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 59, done.
remote: Total 59 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 59
Receiving objects: 100% (59/59), 14.83 KiB | 197.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (22/22), done.
$ julia  
 
(@v1.5) pkg> generate LeafletJS
 Generating  project LeafletJS:
    LeafletJS/Project.toml
    LeafletJS/src/LeafletJS.jl

$ cp -r LeafletJS.jl/* LeafletJS/.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$ cd LeafletJS                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
LeafletJS $ julia  

(@v1.5) pkg> dev .
[ Info: Resolving package identifier `.` as a directory at `/tmp/jl_temp/LeafletJS/`.
Path `.` exists and looks like the correct package. Using existing path.
  Resolving package versions...
Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
  [b1ddfcb9] + LeafletJS v0.1.0 `../../../../../tmp/jl_temp/LeafletJS`
Updating `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
  [b1ddfcb9] + LeafletJS v0.1.0 `../../../../../tmp/jl_temp/LeafletJS`
```